# How to create custom ListStyle in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to make changes to the `listItem`'s `background`, `rowInsets`  based on multiple conditions. How can I create a `struct` conforming to the `ListStyle` protocol?

I tried conforming to it and get the following code blocks. But I've no idea how to proceed from here.

```
struct CustomListStyle: ListStyle {
    
    static func _makeView<SelectionValue>(value: _GraphValue<_ListValue<CustomListStyle, SelectionValue>>, inputs: _ViewInputs) -> _ViewOutputs where SelectionValue : Hashable {
        
    }
    
    static func _makeViewList<SelectionValue>(value: _GraphValue<_ListValue<CustomListStyle, SelectionValue>>, inputs: _ViewListInputs) -> _ViewListOutputs where SelectionValue : Hashable {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Create representable for UITableView or UICollectionView and anything you want inside.

Comment: But that will mean a lot of overhead in my particular case. Also, I'm using OutlineGroup inside the list. I can't find the equivalent for that in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue in these days. After some investigation, I eventually realized that SwiftUI does not really "allow" us to customize the list style by overriding the `ListStyle` protocol. And I found out that there is no any documentation related to this.

However, it is actually possible (not perfect, but doable) to customize it by using Introspect. Check here for more information: https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect#list